# Today's Date in Contact Form 7 date picker

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am new to WordPress and contact form 7. Is there any possibility to get today's date in the contact form 7 datepicker by default?
I have this short-code is [date* date-299 min-date:0 first-day:1]. It didn't work for me. Is there any necessity for Hooks/Actions?

Help required!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it up using Jquery

```
var date = new Date();
$("#dates").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'd-M-y'
}).datepicker('setDate', date);
```

Where #date is the ID of the Text box field

Comment: Place this within `$(document).ready(function(){}`. It will search for the id and set the date to Current Date in that text box . If so needed you can change the date.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried adding the Jquery to the footer page of my theme. Still it didn't work. Guide me if possible.Thanks!!

Comment: First Check whether an alert pop up during `$(document).ready(f‌​unction(){alert('Test');}`. If it happens then sure you have to check the ID of the input value where you want the Date to display.

Comment: Check to that you have the Jquery Calendar library so that only your `datepicker()` funciton works.

Answer (score 17):

In case someone is still looking for the better answer, it is in documentation:
https://contactform7.com/date-field/

My date field example:

```
[date date-479 date-format:mm/dd/yy min:today+2days]
```

Notice, that only works with **min**!!! 
**min-date** doesn't work. :)

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of searching, the below method is working for me:

```
[date* date-775 date-format:YYYY-MM-DD min:today+1days  id:date class:date]
```